# SVNKit library in Android

Tags: android, svnkit

I am developing an Android application as my Bachelor´s project, and I need it to use some SVN client operations - update and commit. I was searching all over the internet and stackoverflow questions, but it seems to me the only java SVN client library which has been successfully used in Android is SVNKit. But as it is an java library i have encoutered several problems when importing it to an Android project - mostly because it is using some pure java libraries.

My question is, how can I possibly make an SVNKit library (or any other svn client library that can serve my needs) make working in an Android project?

The only topic solving this problem I found [here](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/svnkit-on-the-Android-operating-systems-some-ideas-and-hints-td69.html)

But as this article was published in 2009, after going through SVNkit error parts in my project, I belive that SVNkit has evolved since 2009 and this solution is no longer aplicable.

If someone has any experience with android svn client app that would be great, thanks :)

Comment: What exact problems do you encounter?

Comment: A quick Google search is yeilding [this](http://www.valleytg.com/svn/open/oasvn/trunk/) (use `guest/guest` as an id/psw). Looks like a full solution, have you seen it?

Comment: And the app on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvnlite.android)

Comment: [shoe rat] Thanks a lot, this will certainly help :)

Comment: @ozbek links are broken

Comment: @YoussefDir, sorry for a late reply. Please checkout the GitHub project: https://github.com/briangormanly/oasvn